# Howto update the JavaDoc of a function in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc, doc

I have a function A(int x) with my JavaDoc
/**
* @param a
*/

Now I add a new parameter to A -> A(int x, int y).

Is there a shortkey to update the JavaDoc or do I have to do it myself by adding the line manually ?

Comment: There is an answer for your question here:
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671418/what-is-the-intellij-shortcut-key-to-create-a-javadoc-comment)

Comment: Ok I see "fix doc comment". Right ? I can only access this through 2 times shift and enter "fix doc comment". Is there a faster way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the link above **Mark McDonald**  mentions the option of:

> For anyone else searching for how to get IntelliJ to update javadoc after a code change, you can set this in Settings -> IDE Settings -> Keymap.